# OS X support for custom image format?

Tags: image, macos

I must just be blind - can anyone point to documentation or source code for how to write a software component that allows OS X to support a custom image format system wide?  (I'd like to be able for applications like Preview to be able to display my custom images.)  I seems like it must be possible, but I just can't find the documentation or an example.  Thanks.

Edit: I have gotten some information that leads me to believe this isn't possible.  I did see the Apple sample code about making a service to convert a file, but that isn't what I'm after.  I will leave this open in case someone has faced this before and has found something I can't find.

Comment: This stuff is very deprecated at this point, but this sort of thing used to be possible by writing a QuickTime graphics import component. See, for example, Apple's sample projects [DelegateOnlyComponent](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/DelegateOnlyComponent/Introduction/Intro.html) and [ElectricImageComponent](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/ElectricImageComponent/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: This may get you started... https://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/

Comment: @MarkSetchell I appreciate your reply but I am looking for something like a custom format, quick look plugins work for quick look but I can't use them any where else as far as I know.